# How to login using facebook and google in Slim Framwork?

Tags: php, oauth, facebook-php-sdk, slim, slim-3

> Currently i am using PHP Slim framework version 3 and i would like to
>   login using facebook or google account .

I have created a facebook developer account and use api id and secret key in my code.

below i s my php slim framework code

```
<?php 

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

require 'src/facebook.php';

$app = new \Slim\App; 
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '1277740795608952',
  'secret' => 'c9e0d242e62a82374a043ff286526db7',
));

$app->get('/', function () use ($facebook) {
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
   if($user_id) {
      try {
          $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
          echo "Hi " . $user_profile['name'];
      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
          echo 'Please <a href="' . $facebook->getLoginUrl() . '">login.</a>';
      }
   } else {
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $facebook->getLoginUrl() . '">login with Facebook.</a>';
   }
});

$app->run();
?>
```

> condition goes to else part

`login with facebook`

> and all time i get user id

`0`

> I don't know what i forgot does any one know more about it ?

Answer (score 0):

try put this before the line: "$user_id = $facebook->getUser();"

```
$req_perms = "publish_stream,offline_access,user_status,email,read_stream";

$session = $facebook->getSession();

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('canvas'=>1,'fbconnect' => 0,'req_perms'=>$req_perms));

if (!$session) { echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";exit;}
```